# Solve this set of Lagrange multiplier equations,

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

I'm trying to solve

$$(yz,xz, xy) = (\lambda\frac{2x}{a^2},\lambda\frac{2y}{b^2},\lambda\frac{2z}{c^2})$$

with the constraint equation

$$\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}+\dfrac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$

What's the best way to proceed?  I can't seem to first solve for $\lambda$.

Thanks,

Comment: Which function did you want to optimise???

Comment: Multiply the first equation by $x$, the second by $y$, the third by $z$. It gives you immediately that all terms in the constraint are equal.

Comment: Hi @A.G.  - what a pretty and clever way to solve it.  Thanks so much.  Can I ask you a follow-up question?  There seems to be four critical points that maximizes the function xyz.  Each of x,y, and z have a positive and negative square root.  So taking the negative square roots of both x and y, and taking the positive square root of z gives the maximum value abc/$\sqrt{27}$.

Comment: And similarly for y and z negative or x and z negative.  The fourth case is just to take x, y, z to be all positive.  Does it matter that we found the max at four different locations?  The question only asked to maximize the work done by a force field.  Thanks,

Comment: Hi @chuks sorry I meant to optimize xyz - the library was closing and I had to squeeze in this question on the computer terminal :-).

Comment: Ok. Are user258219 and Lebron James same person?

Answer (score 1):

If any of $x$, $y$, and $z$ is $0$, then two of them are $0$ and the other is not (so as to satisfy $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$).  Thus, $\lambda=0$.  Hence, all such solutions are $(x,y,z,\lambda)=(\pm a,0,0,0)$, $(x,y,z,\lambda)=(0,\pm b,0,0)$, and $(x,y,z,\lambda)=(0,0,\pm c,0)$.

If none of $x$, $y$, and $z$ is $0$, then $$\frac{8\lambda^3 (xyz)}{(abc)^2}=\left(\lambda\frac{2x}{a^2}\right)\left(\lambda\frac{2y}{b^2}\right)\left(\lambda\frac{2z}{c^2}\right)=(yz)(zx)(xy)=(xyz)^2\,.$$ 
Consequently, $\lambda=\frac{\sqrt[3]{(xyz)(abc)^2}}{2}$.  Now, note that $\lambda \neq 0$, so
$$\frac{x}{y}=\frac{\lambda\left(2x/a^2\right)}{\lambda\left(2y/b^2\right)}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2=\frac{yz}{zx}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2\,,$$
so
$$\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2=\left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^2\,,\text{ or }\frac{|x|}{|a|}=\frac{|y|}{|b|}\,.$$
Similarly, $\frac{|y|}{b}=\frac{|z|}{c}$.  That is, to comply with $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$, we must have
$$\frac{|x|}{|a|}=\frac{|y|}{|b|}=\frac{|z|}{|c|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\,.$$
With $(x,y,z)=\left(u\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}},v\frac{b}{\sqrt{3}},w\frac{c}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$ where $u,v,w\in\{-1,+1\}$, we get $\lambda=\frac{(uvw)(abc)}{2\sqrt{3}}$.  Hence, there are $8$ solutions
$$(x,y,z,\lambda)=\left(u\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}},v\frac{b}{\sqrt{3}},w\frac{c}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{(uvw)(abc)}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)\,,$$
where $u,v,w\in\{-1,+1\}$.

**P.S.**  Are you trying to optimize $xyz$ given that $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$?  There is a very simple AM-GM solution to this problem.

Comment: Hi @batominovski, yes I want to optimize xyz on the level curve g=1.  I am intrigued - how can you solve it with AM-GM?  Thanks :-)

Comment: **An AM-GM Solution:**

Using the AM-GM Inequality, we get $$1=\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}\geq3\sqrt[3]{\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}\right)\left(\frac{y^2}{b^2}\right)\left(\frac{z^2}{c^2}\right)}\,.$$  Therefore, $|xyz|\leq \frac{|abc|}{3\sqrt{3}}$.  The equality holds iff $(x,y,z)=\left(\pm\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}},\pm\frac{b}{\sqrt{3}},\pm\frac{c}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

We have: $3(xyz)^2 = 3xy\times yz \times zx = \dfrac{24xyz\times \lambda^3}{a^2b^2c^2}, 3xyz = xyz+xyz+xyz = 2\lambda\left(\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}+\dfrac{z^2}{c^2}\right)=2\lambda \times 1 = 2\lambda\Rightarrow 2\lambda = 3xyz=\dfrac{24\lambda^3}{a^2b^2c^2}\Rightarrow \lambda^2 = \dfrac{a^2b^2c^2}{12}\Rightarrow \lambda = \dfrac{abc}{2\sqrt{3}}$.